# destructuring inner objects with same name property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

hi all I have below object structure that i am trying to get the name of all inner objects using destructuring technique but could not be able to do that, Below is the object structure

```
   {
       massingType {
            id
            name
        }
        ashraeClimateZone {
             id
            name
        }
        sourceOfData {
             id
             name    
        }
        .....
    }
```

and i am doing the destrcturing like as below

```
 constructionSetData.constructionSets.forEach(item => {
    if (
      item.ashraeClimateZone?.id === ashraeClimateZoneId &&
      item.massingType?.id === massingTypeId &&
      item.sourceOfData?.id === energyCodeId
    ) {
      matchedConstructionDataSet.push(item.name);
      const { sourceOfData: name, massingType: name, ashraeClimateZone: name } = item; // getting error here Identifier 'name' has already been declared 
    }
  });
  return matchedConstructionDataSet.length
    ? `${matchedConstructionDataSet.join(', ')}` // here i need to use above names coming from three inner objects
    : 'No construction set found with the current criteria';
```

Could any one please let me know how can i achieve this solution, many thanks in advance!!

Comment: could any one please let me know how do i get each object name with destructuring

Comment: Just check the documentation ;)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

TIP: name is declared 3 times

Comment: `const { sourceOfData: name, massingType: name, ashraeClimateZone: name } = item;` Is the same as writing `const name = item.sourceOfData;` and `const name = item.missingType;`, etc. I think what you were after was more `const { sourceOfData: { name: sourceOfDataName } } = item;` this would essentially be the same as `const sourceOfDataName = item.sourceOfData.name`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using destructuring assignment you can rename any destructured variables. You are currently renaming each "root" key as `name` which is causing duplicate declarations, but it appears you really want to access & destructure the nested `name` property of each.

```
const {
  sourceOfData: {
    name: sourceOfDataName,
  },
  massingType: {
    name: massingTypeName,
  },
  ashraeClimateZone: {
    name: ashraeClimateZoneName,
  },
} = item;
```

Considering *just* the first destructured value, the above

1. destructure assigns `sourceOfData` from `item`
2. destructure assigns the `name` property to `sourceOfDataName`.